# Should one post enhancement requests to Stack Overflow if a developer asks for it?

Tags: discussion

I'm currently trying to find out where to ask a question regarding a program (i.e a specific extension in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)). The question isn't about a bug, nor do I expect there to be an "answer" that would help me. It's more of an enhancement request, since I believe that the way it treats `import as` statement IntelliSense in Python is very counter intuitive and just gets in the way of coding.

Unless I'm mistaken, this doesn't seem like something I should post on Stack Overflow, since there probably isn't a setting I can tweak just for this specific instance. It's more about bringing the developers' attention to a specific topic.

So I would have assumed this should go to the GitHub page as an issue (maybe I'm wrong there too, I'm not sure where else this could go). However, on the GitHub page, they recommend that enhancement requests be posted on Stack Overflow and tagged as `visual-studio-code+python`.

Would it be OK to post this type of question on Stack Overflow as they say then? It seems a bit much for the entire `python` tag to get a question which is just an enhancement request.

Comment: If the developer asks for people to post enhancement requests on Stack Overflow, he might need to be educated about what's on topic here. [We're not customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/7296893). GitHub likely is the most appropriate place to ask this.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Also, this is not aimed at you, but do you know why I'm getting downvoted? I ask because sometimes I notice it happening, and presumably it means there's something wrong with my question (in fact, this very question is an attempt at avoiding that on the main StackOveflow page). So for next time, did I post this in the wrong place or what?

Comment: Presumably some people are downvoting to tell you that they think it's not a good idea to post this question on StackOverflow. Downvotes don't affect your reputation here so there isn't really that much to worry about from them.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions

Comment: It wasn't VSCode that was sending users here for enhancement requests, it was just the github page of a specific extension.

Comment: Which extension specifically, if you don't mind sharing? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python does not contain such guidance as far as I can see.

Comment: You probably misunderstood the following from their issue template: *"Do you have a question instead of a bug report or enhancement request? Please ask it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code+python."* It says that questions should be posted on SO, it doesn't say enhancement requests should be posted on SO.

Comment: @Stijn Ah now I see, yeah that was my bad, I misread it. Sorry.